# Binary search tree insert method

Tags: python, insert, binary-search-tree

I have written a binary search tree insertion method, but it doesn't work properly. It compiles. But it doesn't actually insert anything. I appreciate your help.

```
    def insert(self,root):
        if root==None:
            root=self
        else:
            if self.key<=root.key:
                self.insert(root.left)
            elif self.key>root.key:
                self.insert(root.right)

root=BST(5)
n2=BST(2)
n7=BST(7)
n9=BST(9)
n2.insert(root)
n7.insert(root)
n9.insert(root)
```

Comment: Do you not set root.left or root.right? I feel that would be necessary in order to insert it. You're just calling the function recursively, then setting a function argument to an object.

Comment: I am trying to assign them on line "root=self". Is this incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: That would be incorrect. You're setting the function argument root, to self. I'm not familiar with how your binary tree would be structured, but I would assume you would want something like this

`
if root==None:
    if value<root:
       root.left.value=value
    else:
       root.right.value=value
`